# Apache Drill configuration

Tags: hadoop, apache-drill

I need to add storage plugins for Apache Drill (basically PSVs) but I am unable to find the configuration file where I could add following lines:-

```
 "formats": {
   "psv": {
     "type": "text",
     "extensions": [
       "tbl"
     ],
     "delimiter": "|"
   }
}
```

Note that the current solutions to open a the local host url in a web browser is not feasible. I don't want to expose the port and IP to Internet. Currently I do double hop ssh to reach my server which hosting drill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can post to Drill's REST API:

```
curl -X POST -H “Content-Type: application/json” -d ‘{ “name”:dfs, “config” {“type”: “file”, "connection": "hdfs:///", “enabled”: true, "workspaces": {"root": {"location": "/", "writable": false, "defaultInputFormat": null}}, "formats": { "psv": { "type": "text", "extensions": [ "tbl" ], "delimiter": "|" }}}’ http://localhost:8047/storage/dfs.json
```

You can also create a [`bootstrap-storage-plugins.json`](https://github.com/apache/drill/blob/master/contrib/storage-hbase/src/main/resources/bootstrap-storage-plugins.json) file and include it on the classpath when starting Drill and it should be loaded when Drill boots up.

Comment: Thanks for the help. However I have decided not to use Apache Drill. I was mistaking it as replacement of Hive.

Comment: Apache Drill can certainly be considered a replacement for Hive. What is Drill not doing that Hive is? Just curious.

Comment: I am quite novice in Big Data stack but what I understood is that Drill is a replacement of Infobright. In Hive you can load csv at runtime, execute map reduce SQL queries. Overall SQL queries will take more time as Hive doesn't do any indexing, processing on the table we have imported csv into.

In drill I understood that you create a data warehouse by specifying csv's at configuration. Drill will then create its datastore, replicate data in its tables, do processing. I believe drill will consume more disk space but will execute queries really fast. [1/2]

Comment: So Hive is best suited for taking Adhoc Batch queries but drill is for real time queries...!

Please correct me, There is good chance that I am wrong. [2/2]

Comment: Hive essentially leverages hadoop and launches mapreduce jobs and is very useful for batch queries. Drill on the other hand is based on Google's Dremel which is more useful for interactive adhoc queries. 
(Link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6607552/what-is-googles-dremel-how-is-it-different-from-mapreduce)

Comment: Drill does not replicate any data into it's tables, it address the data in-place in the HDFS filesystem. Drill's configuration allows you to point at a directory/file and query it as it lies, no ETL or schema is required. Drill will not take up extra disk space.

Comment: @ChrisMatta can you plz have a look on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31962882/exception-in-using-bootstrap-storage-plugins-json-file-for-storage-plugin-in-apa

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use Drill UI.
Once Drill is started the Drill UI is available on port 8047 (default). 
Once in UI click on Storage and you can see all the Enabled and Disabled storage plugins and you can add/create additional storage plugins from here.