# Exception in using bootstrap-storage-plugins.json file for storage plugin in apache-drill

Tags: apache-drill

I want to add storage plugins for `MongoDB` in `apache-drill`. After reading docs, I came to know that programmatically I can do that in two ways:

1. Rest API
2. using bootstrap-storage-plugins.json for configuration

I am using 2nd way for my java code.

**Useful portion of my code:**

```
Connection conn = new Driver().connect("jdbc:drill:zk=local",null);
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("show databases");
        while (rs.next())
        {
            String SCHEMA_NAME = rs.getString("SCHEMA_NAME");
            System.out.println(SCHEMA_NAME);
        }
```

**bootstrap-storage-plugins.json:**

```
{
  "type": "mongo",
  "connection": "mongodb://localhost:27017/",
  "enabled": true
}
```

But on firing

```
"select * from mongo.testDB.`testCollection`";
```

I got following exception:

> org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.SqlValidatorException 
>       SEVERE: org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.SqlValidatorException: Table 'mongo.testDB.testCollection' not found
>       Aug 12, 2015 3:47:05 AM org.apache.calcite.runtime.CalciteException 
>       SEVERE: org.apache.calcite.runtime.CalciteContextException: From line 1, column 15 to line 1, column 19: Table
>   'mongo.testDB.testCollection' not found
>       java.sql.SQLException: PARSE ERROR: From line 1, column 15 to line 1, column 19: Table 'mongo.testDB.testCollection' not found

**`bootstrap-storage-plugins.json` is in my classpath. Do I need to provide and additional information?**

**Edit:**

I tried `show databases` query and it's not showing schemas from `MongoDB`. It's only showing:

```
INFORMATION_SCHEMA
cp.default
dfs.default
dfs.root
dfs.tmp
sys
```

Comment: What does Drill return when you run `show databases;` ? It should show an entry for each mongotdb table as `mongodb.tablename`. Do any of the tables show up?

Comment: show databases doesn't show collections for me (it shows mongo.local and mongo.test databases). I use mongo.test and then show tables, and then i see my collection zips in the list. I can query the collection using just the colleciton name and no backticks: select * from zips limit 10; But I'm using the Drill shell. Maybe you're hitting https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DRILL-3466.

Comment: @ChrisMatta show databases is not showing schemas from mongodb

Comment: In distributed mode, the bootstrap method works only the first time you bring up a cluster. The problem is related to zookeeper persistent data. In embedded mode, the bootstrap mode should work but has never been tested. The Drill expert is trying to get more info about embedded mode/bootstrap but in the meantime recommends using the REST API to set the storage plugin config programmatically.

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DRILL-2003

Answer (score 0):

Your query looks like a query on the file system. Using the mongo storage plugin configuration, there's no workspace or file, so try making your query look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM testCollection;
```

Make sure you're using the right database name and your and collection is listed (SHOW DATABASES and SHOW TABLES).

This [published correction](http://drill.apache.org/docs/mongodb-storage-plugin/) of the Drill doc might help.